# GGplot and gridExtra with one plot facet_grid - how to have perfectly fit scales?

Tags: r, gridextra

I am using `grid.arrange()` to put two plots in one. However, one of the plots is created using `facet_grid` and thus has additional text on its right side. Therefore the scales do not perfectly match (see picture below)

[image: picture of labels not being perfectly on top of each other]

I want the scales to be perfectly above or underneath each other, 10 above 10, 9 above 9 and so on. Can anybody help on how to achieve this? Should I remove the text from the facet_grid? If so, how can I do so?

**EDIT**
Exampe for illustrating my issue

```
g1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = neu1, aes(x = AGE, y = costs,
                               colour = Type, shape = Type),
             size = 3)+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1,10), breaks = seq(0,10,1))+
  ylab("Costs")

g2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = neu1, aes(x = AGE, y = costs,
                              colour = Type, shape = Type),
             size = 3)+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1,10), breaks = seq(0,10,1))+
  ylab("Costs")+
  facet_grid(Type ~.)
grid.arrange(g1,g2, nrow = 2)
```

This gives the following output as to be seen in the picture above, for this example two plots do not make too much sense, it is just for illustration.

As you can see, the gridlines for each number are not on top of each other, for example AGE 10 on the upper plot is further to the right side than on the lower plot. Thank you once more to all!

Comment: The `cowplot` package may be able to help here. It has tools for axis alignment. If not, you can edit the grobs directy after a `ggplot_build()`.

Comment: thank you for the hint about cowplot. I have not used it before. could you maybe explain a little more about the ggplot_build() command? What do you mean by editing the grobs?

Comment: Can you provide a small example which can be used to demonstrate different concepts?

Comment: I just edited my original post, I hope this helps to illustrate my question.

Comment: [ggarrange](https://github.com/baptiste/egg) i think should work here

Comment: hello user20650, could you maybe outline how to use ggarrange here? thanks!

Comment: `p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() ;
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(am ~ .) ;
egg::ggarrange(p1, p2, heights = c(1,2))`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove the facet labels with "strip" arguments in theme().

```
p + theme(strip.text = element_blank(), 
    strip.background = element_blank())
```

Where p is the the facet plot from the original post.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I tried it, do happen to know whether I can also move the labels to another place, e.g. above the plot?